# Haskell trying to make class Matrix show instance

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in haskell, please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
    newtype (Matrix a) = Matr [[a]]
    instance Show (Matrix a) where
        show (Matr d) = print d
            where print [] = []
                print (x:xs) = show x ++ "\n" ++ print xs

    No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
    add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says "you need a `Show` instance for the element type of your matrix".

Also `print` is the wrong function to call here - `show` is equivalent to `toString` in languages like java - whereas `print` is an IO-operation that puts a `String` to stdout, you are using a name that has already a meaning.

```
newtype Matrix a = Matr [[a]]

instance Show a => Show (Matrix a) where
    show (Matr xx) = showlines xx
      where showlines [] = ""
            showlines (x:xs) = showelems x ++ "\n" ++ showlines xs
            showelems [] = ""
            showelems (x:xs) = show x ++ " " ++ showelems xs
```

now this `showline`/`showelems` pattern is already a common one the functions are `unlines` and `unwords` but the elements need to be strings already so

```
    show (Matr xx) = let strs = map (map show) xx
                     in unlines $ map unwords xx
```

or a bit terser

```
    show (Matr xx) = unlines $ map (unwords . map show) xx
```

---

here is some example usage of `unlines`/`unwords`

```
$ > ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> putStrLn $ unlines ["a","b"]
a
b

Prelude> putStrLn $ unlines $ map unwords [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
a b
c d

Prelude> putStrLn $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show ) [[1,2],[3,4]]
1 2
3 4
```

@lisyarus' answer shows a lot more what happens behind the scene - but note the output of that show function is different from mine.

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> putStrLn $ concat . intersperse "\n" . map show $ [[1,2],[3,4]]
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print (x:xs) = show x ++ "\n" ++ print xs
```

Here, `x` has type `[a]`. The instance `Show [a]` needs an instance of `Show a`. In other words, you have to tell how to show `a` in order to be able to show `[a]`.

Add a dependency on `Show a` in your instance declaration:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Matrix a) where
    ...
```

By the way, your code can be written using standard library like this:

```
show (Matr d) = concat . intersperse "\n" . map show $ d
```

Note: You need to `import Data.List` in your matrix module for the `intersperse` function!